# Pervasive SQL GRANT syntax

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I've been Googling for half an hour now, and can't seem to find the right place...

How do I add a user and grant that user access to all tables in the database? Found some GRANT snippets, but there is no mentioning of a password, so I assume that can be done on existing users only... But what about adding that user, and password identification?

PS: Not sure if it belongs more here, or on serverfault (neither has this answer already)... So feel free to move it, if it should be on serverfault instead.

Comment: It's Pervasive SQL. I'm not sure which version is that though. But I think it's 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is two command in Pervasive SQL as well.

```
CREATE USER jsmith WITH PASSWORD password

GRANT SELECT ON * TO jsmith
```

Full documentation on both are in the [SQL Syntax Reference](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv10/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/syntaxref.4.1.html) guide on Pervasive's site.
One thing to note, most PSQL databases do not have security enabled by default and do not require a user to login.  The CREATE USER and GRANT statements will return an error if you try to run them on a database that does not have security enabled.

Comment: That seems to work like it should... Now I can login, but when I try to select from one of the tables - I get `Unable to open table: TableName., SQL state S1000`... Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Is there anything else in the message?  What tool are you using to open the tables?

Comment: Well, here is a full message... `Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Unable to open table: TableName., SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in D:\file\path.php on line 222`. I'm using PHP to connect and run these queries.

Comment: Can you access the table through the Pervasive Control Center?  If not, does it give the same error or a different one?

Answer (score -2):

It's 2 commands: CREATE USER and GRANT after.

From MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual

Normally, a database administrator
first uses CREATE USER to create an
account, then GRANT to define its
privileges and characteristics. For
example:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)

Comment: CREATE USER and GRANT are common SQL statements

Comment: [CREATE USER](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv10/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/syntaxref.4.27.html#1941392)

Comment: [GRANT](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv10/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/syntaxref.4.49.html#165945)