# Filter SQL query string to disallow writes

Tags: sql, security, pervasive-sql

I have a Pervasive SQL 12 database that I need to read from a certain application, but should never write to.  There's a PHP PDO wrapper function I use to handle the parameterization and set up the various options I use routinely. I'm connecting via the Windows ODBC 64-bit driver, using proper parameterized queries with "?" placeholders. The 32-bit ODBC driver allows read-only connections, but the 64 doesn't.

My question is: Is there a way to filter the Query string itself to only allow "read" (SELECT) queries?

At its most basic, I could use PHP to ensure the query begins with the word "SELECT", and doesn't contain any semicolons (which would likely indicate a break and a start to a second query).

Is there anything else I should look for? Is it possible in SQL to do a SELECT query that has an UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT as a subquery?  Or similar weirdness that could bypass this type of filter?

I don't really expect an actively malicious user, so much as I'm trying to prevent accidental/careless useage of modifying queries.

Comment: You can restrict a meta db user to only have read-like permissions.

Comment: @Nae It doesn't appear I can. I'm connecting via the 64-bit ODBC driver, and that driver doesn't allow read-only. (The 32-bit one does. I'm converting 32-bit to 64-bit, but trying to at least somewhat preserve the read-only-ness of the connection.)  NOTE: I corrected the question; this is Pervasive SQL, not MySQL.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461758/pervasive-sql-grant-syntax Pervasive SQL has the `GRANT` command to grant permissions. So you should be able to restrict the user only to `SELECT` queries.

Comment: @Barmar -- For reasons relating to not getting strung up by angry workmates, I do not want to change the database itself in any way. Otherwise an interesting suggestion. (Also: I don't believe the ODBC connector uses authentication, so not sure how I'd specify I'm connecting as that particular user.)

Comment: The only way a `SELECT` query could modify the DB is if it calls a stored procedure that contains `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` queries. Those queries can't be used directly as subqueries.

Comment: @Barmar That sounds like what I was looking for.  So it appears my standard would be sufficient?  String must start with "SELECT", and cannot contain a semicolon ?  (assuming no stored procedures)

Comment: The semicolon prohibition will block queries that contain semicolon inside strings. I don't think PDO allows multiple queries separated by semicolon, so I think you can leave that out.

Comment: The values are all parameterized — the query strings just have “?” placeholders. I don’t know if any other use for semicolons in queries other than termination

Comment: The ODBC driver has to use some sort of authentication like any kind of connection to a database. Adding a new user with read-only rights to a database should be no problem and should disrupt no one else's work. Actually, your db may already have such a user by default or for other purposes, see if you can use it. Having the application filter the queries doesn't sound like it adds much to the database security.